# Is there a way to search and replace something in tcl like dft_scan_si[0] to dft_scan_siX0X, when the 0 is changing numbers?

Tags: tcl

I know how to do the search and replace for one instance, but I was wondering if there is a short way where I am able to replace all of the brackets with X for this specific "statement".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string map](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.html#M34) to find and replace characters in a string

```
set a = {dft_scan_si[0] dft_scan_si[1] dft_scan_si[2]}

set b [string map {[ X ] X} $a

puts $b
```

This should output `dft_scan_siX0X dft_scan_siX1X dft_scan_siX2X`

Comment: Say there are over 100 numbers, is this still the best way to change it all? Would I have to type out every instance or is there a short cut?

Comment: The string `a` is just a list of your entries. It may be loaded from a file or built with a for loop. I just hardcoded it for the example. The important line is the `set b [string map {[ X ] X} $a` which will work for any length string `a`.